# ASP.NET MVC - OutputCacheAttribute - Is it disabled in debug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

Can anyone confirm whether the OutputCacheAttribute caches pages when running as Debug? Or only in Release builds?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm that [OutputCacheAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) caches pages when running in Debug mode.